# How can I join tables from different databases in Azure SQL (SAAS)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Having the older application that joins SQL tables from different databases like this:

```
SELECT a.value, b.value
  FROM databaseA.dbo.tableA AS a
       JOIN databaseB.dbo.tableB AS b
         ON a.thekey == b.thekey
```

Being 3rd party, we have to accept the decision of the main implementor for the customer to use the license Azure SQL SAAS (Software As A Service; I am new to that, sorry if some terms are incorrect).

Is it possible to have `databaseA` and `databaseB` (that part is possible, checked through SSMS) in the Azure SQL and do the same JOIN (that part is unknown to me)?

I tried, but it failed. I do not know if something more have to be done to make the other database visible from each of the databases, or if it is not possible at all.

If it is not possible, what is the recommended technique to replace the old SQL code?

Comment: I think you mean "SAAS" -- software as a service -- not "SAS", a company the write statistics software.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, software as a service. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: It's not a license, it's a deployment type. One could even argue a different product. Quite likely on *different* servers. On-premises, you can only use multiple databases in the same query if they are on the same server. Otherwise you need to create linked servers and pay a performance penalty

Comment: [Azure SQL supports cross-database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical) but all other databases are treated as if they were remote databases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes. I understand that (roughly). I understand that it is different than working within one physical SQL Server. On the other hand, the _different servers_ is probably related to _possible replication_. Is that correct?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It seems that the cross-database queries documentation is the answer. Please, copy that as the comment, so I am able to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you comment said: "I understand that it is different than working within one physical SQL Server. On the other hand, the different servers is probably related to possible replication. Is that correct? ", yes, you're right.

For Azure SQL database(PSSA), we only can use the [elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview) to achieve the cross database query:

- The elastic query feature (in preview) enables you to run a
  Transact-SQL query that spans multiple databases in Azure SQL
  Database. It allows you to perform cross-database queries to access
  remote tables, and to connect Microsoft and third-party tools (Excel,
  Power BI, Tableau, etc.) to query across data tiers with multiple
  databases.

**Note:**
**Make sure the primary database have the permission to access the remote databases. Add the the client IP to their database firewall. The remote database can be in different Azure SQL Server.**

If you are using [Azure SQL managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview) and [Azure SQL Server on Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-on-azure-vm-iaas-what-is-overview), you can run this across query like on-premise SQL Server.